# How can I get rid of the taskbar tooltips in Mate?

Tags: mate, tooltip

As in the pictures, I get annoying tooltips in taskbar. The DE is Mate. How can I config Mate not to show them?

[image: Tooltip example]

[image: Tooltip example]